# Simplest way to blank the Macintosh display until a key is pressed?

Tags: macos, screensaver

What is the simplest way to blank a Macintosh screen (completely black) and unblank it **only on keystroke** (not mouse movement)? I'm happy to pursue any of these implementations:

- Create a completely custom program that blanks the screen (or turns off the display) and awaits a keystroke. (A short gcc/g++ program would be great....)
- Create (or locate) a standard "System Preferences" screensaver that ignores mouse events
- Some configuration trick that makes the existing screensaver system ignore mouse events
- A third-party app, free or commercial

No fancy screensaver graphics wanted - just a blank screen.

I'm an experienced developer (Linux, Windows) but have never written for the Mac. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments on CajunLuke's answer, why not just turn off screen brightness completely when not in use? As far as I know, all Mac keyboards have screen brightness buttons, so you could use them to quickly turn on/off screen brightness when you want to.

Answer (score -1):

Control-Shift-Eject should do what you want. If you have a screensaver password set up, it'll ask for that, too.

Comment: Thanks, but a simple nudge of the mouse unblanks the screen.  Confirmed on our iMac with the latest OS X.

Comment: I use a screen saver password, so I have to enter that to un-blank the screen. That, at least, requires key presses.

Comment: Also, what, ultimately, are you trying to accomplish? Why just awake on keyboard and not mouse? Could you just unplug the mouse (unless it's a laptop, obviously)?

Comment: Goal: I want the display to stay off, period. (Apple is the only manufacturer that doesn't put "off" buttons on its monitors!) The display is in the bedroom and regularly turns on at night when blanked, waking people. (A password prompt would also produce light and probably wake people.) It's a Bluetooth mouse, so there's no "unplugging" really. I simply want a normal screenblanker that actually keeps the display off until commanded to turn back on. :-)

Comment: @DanB: How do you propose to "command" it to turn back on if you're ignoring all keyboard and mouse input because it might be accidental?

Comment: @Cody: See the question again: I want wakeup "only on keystroke."

Comment: @DanB I'm assuming you've tried putting the computer to sleep overnight. (Also, the Bluetooth mice have an off-switch: the door covering the tracking laser.)

Comment: @CajunLuke: thanks for your suggestions. It's true that using a combination of sleep mode, mouse on/off switches, etc., we can probably survive (we have four Macs that we want to stay blank except when in use). But as a programmer, I'm accustomed to making computer do what I want, rather than being at the mercy of the computer's existing features. :-)  So I'd rather go with a technical solution and find (or create) a screensaver that works as described, blanking the screen until a keypress.

Comment: @DanB Do update if you find a solution by posting your own answer and accepting it.